# Why does it take so long to upload a 20mb file to Parse-Server?

Tags: android, parse-server

Parse-Server is owned by Facebook and It takes a few seconds to upload a 5 minute to Facebook.

But It takes me 90 seconds to upload a 20mb video to Parse-Server. The parse docs promised me the service was very fast before I decided to sign up. Was I deceived?